# Can't debug my micro

Tags: embedded, stm32

Since I uploaded my stm32cubef1 firmware version up to 1.6.0, I can't debug anymore my board. I'm using SWSTM32 and ST-LINK/V2.
Once I press the "play" like button, when I try to stop it a Windows opens and it says:

```
"No source available for "dt_TPS()at 0x20000004"
```

where dt_TPS is one of my variables.
In the window at the bottom of the page I read this:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00302-gc211ca5-dirty (2017-07-03-10:41)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v28 API v2 SWIM v6 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : vid/pid are not identical: 0x0483/0x374B 0x0483/0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.239921
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x200001e0 msp: 0x20005000
Info : device id = 0x10016418
Info : flash size = 64kbytes
STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x200001e0 msp: 0x20005000
STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x200001e0 msp: 0x20005000
Info : Padding image section 0 with 4 bytes
STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000003a msp: 0x20005000
STM32F105R8Tx.cpu: target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x200001e0 msp: 0x20005000
Error: address + size wrapped(0xffffffff, 0x00000004)
Error: address + size wrapped(0xffffffff, 0x00000002)
Error: address + size wrapped(0xffffffff, 0x00000004)
Error: address + size wrapped(0xffffffff, 0x00000002)
```

Other infos: my current toolchain is: AC6 STM32 MCU GCC, current builder: Gnu Make Builder and the micro I used is STM32F105R8T6
Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Almost forgot: my micro is STM32F105R8

Comment: You should fix the omission by editing the question, not by adding a comment.  That said the target is clearly indicated in the OCD output. The error message suggests that it is looking for a _function_ `dt_TPS` at a RAM address.  Have you done a clean & build?  The address suggests that you may have set the boot mode to SRAM instead of flash  - does your board have a jumper for that?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be executing code from SRAM rather then flash.  That is unusual, and possibly not intentional.

The processor will execute from SRAM on reset when the BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins are both high.  Normally you load and execute code from flash (BOOT0 low, BOOT1 don't care) - your board may have jumpers for boot mode selection.

Comment: Hi Clifford, thanks for your answer. In my board I used a switch to select the boot mode, and I think it boots from the flash, because if I turn off and then turn on the power supply I can see with the oscilloscope that the mcu is executing my code. I've downgraded my firmware version and everything works now as before. Maybe it's the new firmware version? I don't know but I think I'll stick to the older version until a new update will be available

Comment: @SandroSartoni - the PC addresses shown in your output are clearly in RAM, not flash.  So either execution started there, or it started in flash and transferred to RAM, perhaps due to stack corruption or some other sort of runaway.

Comment: Occam's razor suggests that the error is in your code.  STM32Cube is not 'firmware', its just a library (from which you build _your_ firmware). You should debug by setting a breakpoint at the reset address if it is not getting to main(), and stepping the code to discover where any why it stats exciting from RAM. It is suspicious because 0x02000004 is the reset vector in SRAM bootmode.

Comment: I'll investigate further then. Thanks again, as you can see I'm still a newbie and I still have to learn many things in microcontroller's world